# P ch MOSFET datasheet confusion

Tags: datasheet, pmos

I have a faulty PMOS that I have to replace, but the part seems to be out of stock. [STL6P3LLH6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/3c/90/16/29/a8/76/48/02/DM00064617.pdf/files/DM00064617.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00064617.pdf)

I have found a very similar device spec-wise, but there is some difference between the two. The original part's datasheet has positive Vds, Current throughout the datasheet, while the replacement has the normal negative values on the datasheet.

On the first page of the original part's datasheet, there is a comment like the picture below, which I think it means that the original datasheet's Vds and current is negative in value.

Is it conventional in PMOS datasheet to do this? It's my first time seeing a datasheet like this.

[image]

**Original part**

[image]

**Replacement part**

[image]

Comment: It seems that maker of the datasheet for the STL6P3LLH6 was either being very simplistic and specified positive values for VDS and also VGS knowing that in actuality they are negative values OR they didn’t even realize they made the mistake.

Comment: By the way other data sheets for other P channel MOSFETs have this issue as well. They may specify positive  values for VGS and VDS then somewhere else in datasheet they’ll use negative values.

Answer (score 2):

A P-MOSFET will either have a negative Vds value or a positive Vsd rating mentioned in the datasheet. Typically, you would use this MOSFET as a high side switch with the **Source** being connected to the Voltage Supply and the **Drain** being connected to the load. I'm curious as to why the manufacture refered to the max Vds value as a positive value. But in any case, you will typically see a negative Vds when talking about a P-MOSFETs characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Some manufacturers as Vishay or ST, usually show the positive side of the Drain Characteristics Curve instead of the negative one. For example, look at this one https://www.vishay.com/docs/63199/si2365eds.pdf (same as yours).